# How to initialize ap in a function with unspecified no of arguments if we don't know the start of the list?

Tags: c++, function, variadic-functions

I need to create a function to create a set of integers. As I don't know the no. of arguments, I thought of using the ellipses.

```
   void f1(...)
   {
     va_list ap;
       //how to initialize ap as I don't know the last actual argument as there is no such argument!!!
   }
```

Also, is there any other way to know whether the list has ended instead of supplying a last argument with a value that denotes the end of list????

Please help!!!

Comment: Any kind of list implementation will always have a pointer that points at its first element, usually called `head` or `front`. What kind of list are you using?

Comment: Your function is not C; C requires at least one known argument.

Comment: Where is the set going to be created?  If the function returns no value, it must be created in a global variable because there's nowhere else that it can be put...and using global variables is generally not a good idea.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: In variable arguements, what is the type of list created by va_list?? I mean i don't know much about the stuff with these macros. Can you please post a good explanation about them here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rewrite your function a little.

```
Set &f1(int a1, ...)
{
    Set &new_set = new(Set);
    new_set.add(a1);
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, a1);
    int aN;
    while ((aN = va_arg(args, int)) != -1)
        new_set.add(aN);
    va_end(args);
    return new_set;
}
```

Now, this can be invoked with:

```
Set s1 = f1(1, -1);
Set s2 = f1(1, 2, -1);
Set s3 = f1(1, 2, 3, -1);
```

Note, though, that the number of arguments is known at each call site.  An alternative interface design specifies the number of parameters in the first argument:

```
Set s1 = f1(1, 1);
Set s2 = f1(2, 1, 2);
Set s3 = f1(3, 1, 2, 3);
```

However, if you need to specify an arbitrary number of arguments in a single call, then you need an interface more like:

```
Set &f1(size_t num, const int *array);
```

This allows you to specify the number of items in the array.

Comment: You started your list by specifying a1 as the last actual argument. What if I am not having any actual argument at all????

Comment: Go read the C++ standard; I know how to do it in C where the first argument is mandatory - I don't know how to do it in C++ where it isn't (so I'd have to read the standard, or a text book, to find out; and I'd rather you did that for me than making me do it for you).

Comment: I didn't found any more information than u posted in the book "The C== Programming Language" by bjarne stroustroup. Can you please advice any pther standard book???

Comment: Section 18.7 of C++98, paragraph 3 says: _The restrictions that ISO C places on the second parameter to the `va_start()` macro in header
`<stdarg.h>` are different in this International Standard. The parameter_ parmN _is the identifier of the
rightmost parameter in the variable parameter list of the function definition (the one just before the `...)`.
If the parameter_ parmN _is declared with a function, array, or reference type, or with a type that is not compatible
with the type that results when passing an argument for which there is no parameter, the behavior is
undefined._

Answer (score 2):

Here is [an example of using va_list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxhdxye9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You can get the same effect if you pass an array and a count instead of var args, like this:

```
void f(int[] numbers, int count) {
    // Do stuff
}

int main() {
    int p[] = {1,2,3};
    f(p,sizeof(p)/sizeof(p[0]));
    return 0;
}
```